# Asp.Net MVC 3 Secure Login

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, security, ssl-certificate, antiforgerytoken

I have Asp.Net MVC 3 site that has SSL on entire site.
I do have Login action on controller that accepts userName and password and returns Token that is user for calling other actions in web application.In background that actions calls my REST api.

How can I be sure that valid user will not go to my website, login and after that use Fiddler to extract Token?
After that he will be able to call my REST api using that token to do some malicious stuff...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I be sure that valid user will not go to my website, login and
>   after that use Fiddler to extract Token?

You cannot. But that's the whole point of user authentication **and** authorization. You use authentication to identify your user (after him providing a username and password) and give him a token (authentication cookie) that will be used later to access your API.

You use authorization to restrict what the user can do with this token. For example you can say that only logged in users that belong to the Administrators group could access a given controller action:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult SuperSecret()
{
    ...
}
```

Now even if a user is logged in and posses an authentication token he won't be able to access this controller action unless he belongs to the Administrators group.

Comment: But he will have much higher privileges (scope) to my API because he got TOKEN through my website. So I can say he will be in role administrator as you say...

Comment: @RadenkoZec, this means that basically you haven't implemented authorization in your web site. You have only implemented authentication. Currently if a user has a TOKEN he can do anything on your site. And since you are giving this token to any authenticated user, there's nothing you could do to prevent him from reusing it. If you want to distinguish between different roles of users you will have to implement authorization.